# Invalid Interger shows in PHP error_log

Tags: php, error-log

when I try to error_log an integer which has length of 10 and starting from 0 it shows a different value in php error.log

> tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

I just want to understand why is this happening

with out the 0 in front of the integer `error_log()` shows the exact integer I am passing to the `error_log()`

ex

> error_log(0543219878) => 22737 (with 0 in front)
>
> error_log(5543219878) => 5543219878 (without zero)

Can some one please explain this.

Comment: Numbers with a leading 0 are considered to be octal values. So, the actual value of the integer is not 543219878. If you need to dump it exactly as it is, put it in quotes and make it a string: `error_log("0543219878");`

Comment: thanks Till Helge... actually I was dumping it as string and then I dumped it as an integer that's what made me thinking whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your number is consider as octal number.
The octal numeral system, or oct for short, is the base-8 number system, and uses the digits 0 to 7. Octal numerals can be made from binary numerals by grouping consecutive binary digits into groups of three (starting from the right).

Hope it will help you out to understand this.

Happy coding.